# Read Write issues with Pseudo Terminal in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, mono, pty

I am writing a C++ program that would interact with an external process. The external process is written in C# and runs on mono. Note that I cannot modify the C# code as it is not a program written by me.

In this regard, I first set out by using pipes, which of course as I later realized is fully buffered and hence I faced a lot of sync issues. Essentially the external process had to flush its output after every write and this was not possible.

The next thing that I was about to try out was files, but however I found out that using pseudo-terminals would be more apt in my case. Here is some sample code that I have written:

```
int main()
{
    int fdm, fds, rc, pid;
    bool rValue;
    /* Setup Master pty*/
    rValue = rValue && (fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR)) >= 0 &&
             (rc = grantpt(fdm)) == 0 && (rc = unlockpt(fdm) == 0);
    if (rValue) {
        /* Open Slave pty */
        fds = open(ptsname(fdm), O_RDWR);
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
            perror("fork failed");
        else if(pid == 0) //child
        {
            close(fdm); //close master
            struct termios slave_orig_term_settings;
            struct termios new_term_settings;
            tcgetattr(slaveTTY, &slave_orig_term_settings);
            new_term_settings = slave_orig_term_settings;
            cfmakeraw(&new_term_settings);
            tcsetattr(slaveTTY, TCSANOW, &new_term_settings);

            //redirect I/O of this process
            close(0);
            close(1);
            close(2);
            dup(slaveTTY);
            dup(slaveTTY);
            dup(slaveTTY);

            close(slaveTTY);

            setsid();
            ioctl(0, TIOCSCTTY, 1);

            //launch the external process and replace its image in this process
            execve(argv[0],...);
        }
        else
        {
            close(fds); //close slave
            //Perform some interaction
            write(something using fdm);
            //Assume fdsets declared and set somewhere here
            select(fdm +1,&fdset,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            int readBytes = read(someting using fds);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Assume that the fdset and fdclr for select are being taken care of.

The following issues are being observed in the parent process:

1. Sometimes read returns with readBytes > 0 but there is nothing present in the buffer
2. Sometimes whatever has been written to the terminal is read back
3. Some garbage values such as ^]]49]1R are being dumped on the terminal (this is the actual terminal i.e. my output window)

P.S: When the external process is written in C/C++, this issue is not occuring. Only when I run a C# program in mono.

Comment: Just to clarify, from the [`pipe(2)` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe): "Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe." This means that the pipes themselves are not "fully buffered", but most likely the program you communicate with have its output buffered separately, like writing to `stdout` from a C program.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Agree with your statement. As a matter of fact, this is exactly what the program is doing.

Comment: Where is "slaveTTY" in your code defined? I'm trying to get behind the concept of pseudoterminals myself and am in desperate need of working examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) in python is a good choice if you don't have to do that in `C++`, it will save you a lot of time. And also you can use python freeze tools like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) to convert your python script to standalone binary.